# How to replace init with upstart?

Tags: 14.04, upstart, init

I have a Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS installation, and when I run the following command:

```
ps -p 1
```

I get the following output:

> PID TTY          TIME CMD
>
> 1 ?        00:00:06 init

suggesting I am using `init`?

How do I switch `init` to `upstart` (required by software that I am running on the box). Ideally I would like to use `systemd` but by the looks of it it's not supported by 14.04 (only starting with Ubuntu 15)

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install upstart-sysv
```

But get:

> E: Unable to locate package upstart-sysv

Please suggest what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Upgrade to 16.04 - on my system, PID 1 ==`systemd`

Comment: @waltinator I cannot upgrade to 16.04, because one software package only supports 14.04 TLS :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything.

The kernel always runs `/sbin/init` to start the system, and in 14.04 that's Upstart (and in later versions of Ubuntu a symlink to systemd).

Running

```
/sbin/init --version
```

should tell you which version of Upstart you are running.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But why Ubuntu 16 reports `systemd` when running the same command `ps -p 1` ?

Comment: @Alex Since Ubuntu 15.04, `systemd` is used by default instead of `sysvinit` or `upstart`.

Comment: @luk3yx But why the output is not consistent? 
I would expect `ps -p 1` return `init` in all three cases? Or `systemd`, `init` or `upstart`, whereas it returns `init` when upstart is installed? Is it because `upstart` was based on `init`?

Comment: Unlike Upstart systemd replaces `/sbin/init` with a symlink to `/lib/systemd/systemd` which causes `ps` to show `systemd` as executable name. `ps -p 1 -o cmd ` will still show `/sbin/init`